# how to continuous scroll starting mousedown until mouseup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see there are some similar questions, but I fail to understand the implementation properly. Hence, I am asking this specific to my scenario.

I have jQuery flot chart on my webpage. There are horizontal and vertical jQuery sliders which I have programmed to move the chart horizontally and vertically. Now, I want to place image arrow buttons (left, right, top, bottom) which should allow to scroll the chart continuously on mousedown until mouseup event.

The chart should scroll fixed pixels continuously after say every 0.5 sec when the mousedown button is still there. It should stop once the mouseup occurs. I don't want to use any jQuery plugin to achieve this.

Could anyone please help me writing the code for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I am assuming that you are using the jQuery UI slider.

There are 3 steps to achieve your intent.

1. add the image elements to the page
2. add event listeners to the mousedown and mouseup events on these elements.
3. in each event listener, call the `value` method on the jQueryUI slider element.

You will have to do something like this for step 3

```
//These two declared somewhere in scope for the remainder.
var animationHandler;
function slideLeft(){
    element.slider("value",element.slider("value") + 1)
}


$(elem).mousedown(function(e){
    animationHandler = window.setInterval(slideLeft, 500);
});

$(elem).mouseup(function(e){
    window.clearInterval(animationHandler);
});
```

Then, so long as your current implementation is bound to the slider `change` event, everything should come out in the wash.

This is a fairly high level overview of the required code, but it should get you going in the right direction.

Hope that it helps!

Comment: my main question is about how to achieve continuous scrolling when mousedown event occurs until mouseup. I am aware about how to scroll the chart using slider or custom logic.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to show how to do the continuous scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Just animate the scrollTop parameter of using the

```
$('#foobar').mousedown(function(){
    $('#foobar').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#foobar').height()
    });
});
```

when mousedown. Then on mouseup have it do

```
$('#foobar').mouseup(function(){
    $('#foobar').stop();
});
```

That will stop the scrolling animation. Untested, but that should work.